# How to fetch data from Json file on charts(bar-chart/pie chart etc) in angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Now what I'm doing is getting data straight from the ts file as shown below using ng-2 chart and chart.js:
`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})

export class BarChartComponent {

  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwifruit', 'Blueberry', 'Orange', 'Grapes'];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartPlugins = [];

  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [45, 37, 60, 70, 46, 33], label: 'Best Fruits' }
  ];

}
```

`

HTML file:
`

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
    <canvas baseChart 
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

`

the source is [Angular Charts using ng-2charts and charts.js](https://www.positronx.io/angular-chart-js-tutorial-with-ng2-charts-examples/)

So , what I want now to display the same charts but with json file means from json dummy data please help me to achieve this

Json file:

```
    [
 {
      "name": "Java",
      "data": [12, 10, 19]
    }, 
 {
      "name": "Python",
      "data": [23, 18, 20]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your data :

```js
let data = [ { "name": "Java", "data": [12, 10, 19] }, { "name": "Python", "data": [23, 18, 20] } ]
let colors = ["red","blue","green"]; // must match the array size, or include the color inside data
let chartData = data.map((x,i)=> {
 return {
  label: x.name,
  backgroundColor: colors[i],
  data: x.data
 }
})

console.log(chartData)
```

For Reading External JSON File :

```js
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';

// create a function in service or the component
readJsonFile(path:string){
      return JSON.parse(readFileSync(path, 'utf8'));
}
```

Then You can use the function to get the json and pass it to chartJS

Comment: Hi Ahmed , thanks for the answer ,I'm new to Angular and here is the json data(a file): [
 {
      "name": "Java",
      "data": [12, 10, 19]
    }, 
 {
      "name": "Python",
      "data": [23, 18, 20]
  }
] could you please elaborate a little more that how can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Tushar Hi, so you mean you got the json in the ts and you want to assign it to the chart ?

Comment: Hi @Ahmed ,yes!!! json file is in assests folder here is the function to getData(){
    this.http.get<Bar[]>("assets/bar.json").subscribe(data => {
    this.barData=data;
   })
 } but the data is not visible in chart but is visible in console

Comment: @Tasher can you provide stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `push()` method appends the given elements in the last of the array and returns the length of the new array.
Here the final code to get the data from the json file and shows it to the charts
Also I have used example of this [Link](https://www.positronx.io/angular-chart-js-tutorial-with-ng2-charts-examples/)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  barData: number[]=[];
  title = 'chart';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }

   getData(){
      this.http.get<number[]>("assets/data.json").subscribe(data => {
      this.barData.push(...data);
     })
   }


  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Kiwifruit', 'Blueberry', 'Orange', 'Grapes'];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartPlugins = [];

  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data:[]=this.barData,
      label: 'Best Fruits' }
  ];
  

}
```